# How to validate that FD holds with the closure algorithm

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

How can I validate with the closure algorithm that the FD **CI -> B** holds in a relation **R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)** with FDs:

A,C,E -> F

B,C,D,E -> G

C,I -> E

F,I ->

A -> I.

---

In my try I have first determined the candidate key, by looking at which attribute that not is present at the right side of an FD, which is **(A, C, D, H).**

To show that CI -> B not holds, I compute the closure [image]. Is this enough to say that the FD don't hold because the closure doesn't contain the candidate key? I don't know what to look for, can someone please try to push me the right way?

Comment: Just to make sure: you're trying to prove that CI->B does NOT hold in the relation R?

Comment: That's right, I ended up using the chase algorithm to show that no row is without subscript.

Comment: You wrote `F,I -> `, which seems to be missing the right-hand side.